# remove : in 12:45 (java)

Tags: java

time 12:45 
i want to remove : in java .. i just need 1245 ..How can i do that?

Comment: Is the format ALWAYS going to be XX:XX (where X are numbers)?

Comment: A quick look at the java string api would solve that problem.. there are replace functions for that.

Comment: What does this have to do with NSXMLParser?

Comment: @Rafe Kettler:  For that matter, what's it have to do with date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String time = "12:45".replace( ":", "" ); // "1245"
```

If you  have [Apache Coomons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) in your classpath, and you are not sure that time is not null, you could use [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html):

```
time = StringUtils.remove( time, ":" );
```

this way is more compact than writing

```
if ( time != null ) {
    time = time.replace( ":", "" );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is the "replace" method.

```
s = s.replace(':','');
```

If you want to get fancy:

```
s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

This will remove all non-alpha numeric characters (including your ':')

All right there in the JavaDoc.

Comment: I did the same mistake, s.replace(':', '') will be not compiled.. 'Invalid character constant'

Comment: DOH! Oh well, you win for mentioning StringUtils. :)

Answer (score 2):

If `"12:45"` is a string, then just use `"12:45".replaceAll(":", "")`.

Comment: `replaceAll` uses regex and would be an overkill for this. `replace` should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
String strTime = "12:45";
strTime.replace(':','');
```

Answer (score 1):

For the easiest method, use replace:

```
String time = "12:45";
time = time.replace(':', "");
```

but you can use regular expressions:

```
Pattern pattern = new Pattern("(\\d{1,2}):(\\d{1,2})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("12:45");
String noColon = matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2);
```

or the String API:

```
String time = "12:45";
int colonIndex = time.indexOf(':"';
String noColon = time.substring(0, colonIndex) + 
    time.substring(colonIndex + 1, time.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like what others told, a method as simple as `String`'s `replace` should suffice, but since i suspect your input is a date, have a look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) too.